# Catching downloads / saving backups in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, download, electron

Is it possible for me to "catch" the downloads that occur in my Electron app and save backups of them or automatically save them in a given folder? I do have Express setup, if that helps. The download I'm trying to catch is occurring in an iFrame.

I've been looking into [Electron download manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-download-manager) but I can't get it to work the way I want and the documentation online isn't much for my specific case.

What I've tried is this, in my main/index.js file:

```js
const DownloadManager = require("electron-download-manager"); 
DownloadManager.register({
  downloadFolder: path.join(__dirname, 'docs')
});
```